# After building b2, lib are generated fine, but I get linker error LNK1181 cannot open input file 'C:\boost_1_77_0\stage.obj'

Tags: visual-c++, boost, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, b2

After building bootstrap, it generated b2 but it did not generate bjam(I guess that should be fine because b2 is the new name and bjam is the new one). All the libraries are generated fine in Stage/lib. But I get this error now LNK1181. looks like that stage.obj file is not generated, not sure why.

Is there any way I can Ignore this error? This code was written in 1997 maybe in VS2013, we don't even use boost anymore. But there are so many dependencies, I have to use it. FYI same code works fine in VS2003.

Any help would be appreciated, I am a newbee to visual studio(Hope this question is not silly).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFQVx.png)

Comment: It must be something in your set up as I don't see any such file in boost. The path is very suspicious as there would be no obj file in the boost root. Check your linker dependencies in your project.

Comment: Yes! you are right. I found out that, I added the folder "..\boost\stage" in Properties --> Configuration properties --> Linker --> Input --> Additional Dependencies. When I cleared that, I got the fault regarding cannot open "libboost_thread-vc142-mt-gd-x32-1_77.lib". Then I had to add add all the libraries to that project by "add existing items" option. That's how I got rid of errors regarding boost. Thank you for commenting!

Comment: Set an environmental variable, `BOOST_ROOT` to your boost folder. When you version boost you won't have to update projects, just `BOOST_ROOT`.  Then set 'Additional Library Directories` with `$(BOOST_ROOT)/stage/lib` Then all the libs will be automatically available. You won't have to include them separately.

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.